# Display a different page for localhost?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I've got an ASP.NET-hosted WCF application. At the moment, it displays a `403.14 - Forbidden: The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.` error.

I'd like to replace this with something friendlier. However, I'd like to display a different page to `localhost` than to other visitors. The `localhost` page should have a little bit more information about where to look in the documentation for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Default.aspx` to your WCF project. In the code behind you can add the following line in your `Page_Load`

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal) 
{
  // Show localhost information 
  // or use Server.Transfer to move to another aspx file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
```

and then display whatever you want or redirect according to isLocal.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the redirectmode RemoteOnly in your webconfig. Then your remote connections will display your custom errorpage, but locally you will recieve the yellow screen of death.

```
<system.web>
<customErrors defaultRedirect="SiteErrorPage.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
</customErrors>
<system.web>
```

Comment: That doesn't give him the option to show some documentation text on localhost